# How to find the match between two lists and write the output based on matches?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

I am not sure if I put the question title appropriately. But, I have tried to explain the problem below. Please suggest appropriate title if you can think for this problem.

**Say I have two types of list data:**

```
list_headers = ['gene_id', 'gene_name', 'trans_id'] 
# these are the features to be mined from each line of `attri_values`

attri_values = 

['gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"', 'gene_version "1"', 'gene_source "jgi"', 'gene_biotype "protein_coding"']
['gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"', 'gene_version "1"', 'trans_id "scaffold_200001.1"', 'transcript_version "1"', 'exon_number "1"', 'gene_source "jgi"', 'gene_biotype "protein_coding"', 'transcript_source "jgi"', 'transcript_biotype "protein_coding"', 'exon_id "scaffold_200001.1.exon1"', 'exon_version "1"']
['gene_id "scaffold_200002.1"', 'gene_version "1"', 'trans_id "scaffold_200002.1"', 'transcript_version "1"', 'exon_number "3"', 'gene_source "jgi"', 'gene_biotype "protein_coding"', 'transcript_source "jgi"', 'transcript_biotype "protein_coding"', 'exon_id "scaffold_200002.1.exon3"', 'exon_version "1"']
```

I am trying to make a table based on matches of the `list in the header` and `attribute in the attri_values`.

```
output = open('gtf_table', 'w')
output.write('\t'.join(list_headers) + '\n') # this will first write the header

# then I want to read each line
for values in attri_values:
    for list in list_headers:
        if values.startswith(list):
            attr_id = ''.join([x for x in attri_values if list in x])
            attr_id = attr_id.replace('"', '').split(' ')[1]
            output.write('\t' + '\t'.join([attr_id]))

        elif not values.startswith(list):
            attr_id = 'NA'
            output.write('\t' + '\t'.join([attr_id]))

        output.write('\n')
```

**Problem:** is that when the matching strings from `list of list_headers` is found in `values of attri_values` all works well, but when there is no match there are lots of repeat 'NA'.

**Final expected outcome:**

```
gene_id    gene_name    trans_id
scaffold_200001.1    NA    NA
scaffold_200001.1    NA    scaffold_200001.1
scaffold_200002.1    NA    scaffold_200002.1
```

Post edit:
**This the problem with how I have written my `elif` (because for every non-match it will write 'NA').** I tried to move the condition of `NA` in different way but no success. **If I remove the `elif` it get th output as (`NA` is lost):**

```
gene_id    gene_name    trans_id
scaffold_200001.1
scaffold_200001.1    scaffold_200001.1
scaffold_200002.1    scaffold_200002.1
```

Answer (score 1):

python has a `find` method for strings, which you can use to iterate each list header for each attri_values. Try using this function:

```
def Get_Match(search_space,search_string):
    start_character = search_space.find(search_string)

    if start_character == -1:
        return "N/A"
    else:
        return search_space[(start_character + len(search_string)):]

for  i in range(len(attri_values_1)):
    for j in range(len(list_headers)):
        print Get_Match(attri_values_1[i],list_headers[j])
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer using pandas

```
import pandas as pd

# input data
list_headers = ['gene_id', 'gene_name', 'trans_id']

attri_values = [
['gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"', 'gene_version "1"', 'gene_source "jgi"', 'gene_biotype "protein_coding"'],
['gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"', 'gene_version "1"', 'trans_id "scaffold_200001.1"', 'transcript_version "1"', 'exon_number "1"', 'gene_source "jgi"', 'gene_biotype "protein_coding"', 'transcript_source "jgi"', 'transcript_biotype "protein_coding"', 'exon_id "scaffold_200001.1.exon1"', 'exon_version "1"'],
['gene_id "scaffold_200002.1"', 'gene_version "1"', 'trans_id "scaffold_200002.1"', 'transcript_version "1"', 'exon_number "3"', 'gene_source "jgi"', 'gene_biotype "protein_coding"', 'transcript_source "jgi"', 'transcript_biotype "protein_coding"', 'exon_id "scaffold_200002.1.exon3"', 'exon_version "1"']]

# process input data
attri_values_X = [dict([tuple(b.split())[:2] for b in a]) for a in attri_values]

# Create DataFrame with the desired columns
df = pd.DataFrame(attri_values_X, columns=list_headers)

# print dataframe
print df
```

Output

```
               gene_id  gene_name             trans_id
0  "scaffold_200001.1"        NaN                  NaN
1  "scaffold_200001.1"        NaN  "scaffold_200001.1"
2  "scaffold_200002.1"        NaN  "scaffold_200002.1"
```

Without pandas is easy as well. I already gave you `attri_values_X`, then you are almost there, just remove the keys from the dictionary you do not want.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to write a function that will be helpful to parse your data. I tried to modify the original code you posted, what complicates the matter here is the way you store your data that need to be parsed, anyway I'm not in a position to judge, here's my code:

```
def searchHeader(title, values):
    """"
    searchHeader(title, values) --> list 

    *Return all the words of strings in an iterable object in which title is a substring, 
    without including title. Else write 'N\A' for strings that title is not a substring.
    Example:
             >>> seq = ['spam and ham', 'spam is awesome', 'Ham is...!', 'eat cake but not pizza']
             >>> searchHeader('spam', attri_values)
             ['and', 'ham', 'is', 'awesome', 'N\\A', 'N\\A'] 
    """
    res = [] 
    for x in values: 
        if title in x: 
            res.append(x)
        else:
            res.append('N\A')                     # If no match found append N\A for every string in values

    res = ' '.join(res)
    # res = res.replace('"', '')                  You can use this for your code or use it after you call the function on res
    res = res.split(' ')
    res = [x for x in res if x != title]          # Remove title string from res
    return  res
```

Regular expressions can be handy in such cases too. Parse your data with this function and then format the results to write a table to files. This function uses only one `for` loop and one list comprehension where in your code you use two nested `for` loops and one list comprehension.

Pass each header string individually to the function, like in the following:

```
for title in list_headers: 
    result = searchHeader(title, attri_values)
    ...format as table...
    ...write to file...
```

If it's possible, consider moving from a simple list to a dictionary for your `attri_values`, that way you can group your strings with their headers:

```
attri_values = {'header': ('data1', 'data2',...)}
```

In my perspective, this is way better than using lists. Also note, you're overriding `list` name in your code, this is not a good thing to do, that's because `list` actually the builtin class that creates lists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using dictionary will be complicated since these is just a small part of the big data. I thought simple nested for-loop would solve it. Btw, I am getting `type error at `result = searchHeader(list_headers, attri_values)`

Comment: @everestial007 My bad! I should've passed `title` instead of `list_headers` to the function: `result = searchHeader(title, attri_values)`. Could this be the consequence of writing code late at night :P?

Comment: I understand the consequence of being too much infront of the computer and/or being sleepy. Btw, the code is still not able to work the problem for me. I tried changing something like **instead of `if title in x:` I think it should be `if x.startswith(title)` reason being there won't be a hit in list to list comparison unless all strings are matched**. I also tried changing other things but no luck. Can you please give me a full working example? - would that be possible. Please upvote the question so other more attention to this question too.

Comment: @everestial007 See this code to get the idea how to use the function, BTW, I used `print` to print the results for testing you could write the results to file after you format it to a table: [test.py](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/726f9c0fc7ec43556b974cca8a6f5f15). You just need to format the output of the provided function as a table and then write it to output file.

Comment: @everestial007 If you're stuck with writing the table here's [my code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/85eb34e7030d0b9f0e565ddc951841a9). Though it still prints N/A for unmatched strings, I've included N/A just to satisfy `zip`, `zip` runs until the shortest iterable in its argument list, thus removing other elements; in our case it removes string values from `attri_values`. See the documentation of `zip` to know more or run `help(zip)`. Study the code and you'll find it easy just like lemon squeezy! :)